# monitor services running in lxc container in ubuntu server

Tags: nagios, lxc

I want to monitor services running in lxc such as nginx, node, database, ect.. I have installed lxc in our production server to have service run in separate containers like database run in one lxc container while nginx run in another lxc container.

I tried with [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) to monitor our production server but nginx and database are installed in separate lxc containers. I have no idea how to monitor services that are running in lxc containers. I tried with nagios plugin [nagios-check_lxc_resources](https://github.com/deimosfr/nagios-check_lxc_resources), but this plugin will tell me how much memory the container utilizing, no pulgin to monitor services running inside lxc. Is there any plugin to monitor lxc services? or else, Is there any other alternative solution for my requirement?

**Things I have done:**
Installed nagios in local server and made it monitor production server.

Answer (score 0):

You would treat them as any other host from your Nagios installation provided you have configured [networking](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-network).